# htaccess url rewrite. I'm in a loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This question has been asked too many times, but I don't realize what I'm doing wrong.
I want to mention that I am new to htaccess and mod_rewrite.

I have the page http://localhost/product.php?c=category&p=product which I'd like to rewrite to http://localhost/category/product.

Tried to change the ruler order but the other rulers no longer works.

Htaccess code:

```
# rewrite search page
RewriteRule ^q-([^/]+)/page-(.*)/?$ search.php?q=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^q-([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^q/?$ search.php?q [NC,L]
RewriteRule cautare(/)? cautare.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^multisearch/?$ multisearch.php [NC,L]

# rewrite /category to /index.php?c=category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#----------------Old version----------------------#
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/?c=$1 [L,QSA]


# rewrite /category to /index.php?t=tab
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^t/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/?t=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^t/([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ /index.php/$2?t=$1 [L,QSA]


# rewrite /category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
# to /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#----------------Old version----------------------#
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ /index.php/$2?c=$1 [L,QSA]


# rewrite /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
# converts any /name-val/ to query parameter name=val in every rewrite
# stopping when there is no part left after /index.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

# rewrite product page
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)(/)?$ product.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

As it is, if I click on the product page nothing happens(just a refresh).

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302/404 URLs you get.

Comment: All are 200. It redirects me to http://localhost/category/product, but results are from http://localhost/category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .htaccess appears to be overly complicated. I am making an attempt to simplify this a bit:

```
# rewrite search page
RewriteRule ^q-([^/]+)/page-(.*)/?$ search.php?q=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^q-([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^q/?$ search.php?q [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(cautare|multisearch)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite /category to /index.php?t=tab
RewriteRule ^t/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?t=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^t/([^/]+)/([^-]+.+)/?$ index.php/$2?t=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# rewrite /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
# converts any /name-val/ to query parameter name=val in every rewrite
# stopping when there is no part left after /index.php
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

# rewrite /category/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes
# to /index.php/brand-mybrand/country-mycountry/offer-yes/new-yes?c=category
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+-.+)/?$ index.php/$2?c=$1 [L,QSA]

# rewrite product page
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]

# rewrite /category to /index.php?c=category
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It works, except RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)(/.*)?$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC] getting a 404

Comment: something like http://localhost/candies/brand-haribo/

Comment: brand- is a filter

Comment: But between `http://localhost/candies/brand-haribo/` and `http://localhost/category/page/` there is no way to identify what page it is.

Comment: Should i use something like  localhost/c/candies/brand-haribo ?

Comment: Or for the filter.../filter/brand-haribo/weight-200g  i think is better

Comment: yes definitely and also clarify how `/filter/brand-haribo/weight-200g` should be rewritten?

Comment: Thank for your time.